# Bash: editing var name using Regex

Tags: bash, file

I have a bash script which extract the names of the looped files and make some modifications in the names

```
#this is the example if initial file: rmsf_visu_AT1_dry_apo.2rep.step7_1.pdb
#this is expected name after post-processing: AT1_dry_apo.2rep
# this is script which do it:
for pdb in ${output}/*.pdb ; do
name=$(basename "$pdb")
name="${name/.step*_*/}"
name="${name/.pdb/}"
name="${name/_visu/}"
name="${name/rmsf_/}"
echo "I am sending ${name} to Chimera!"
```

A question:
1 - how to merge all the following modifications made with one file in a one string

```
name="${name/.step*_*/}"
name="${name/.pdb/}"
name="${name/_visu/}"
name="${name/rmsf_/}"
```

2 - for a file which consist of some date in any place of the file name in a digit format like dd-mm-yyyy, how to remove the date using the same operator like name="${name/date/}"?

Comment: What are the entities that could vary in this string `rmsf_visu_AT1_dry_apo.2rep.step7_1.pdb`? e.g. `1` after AT or `2` before `rep`? Could you give more examples

Comment: everything can be varried :-) so I need only some modification of my example to merge it in one command. but most important how to remove the date properly which may be in any place of the filename?

Comment: @Own12121325: You won't get any further assistance in this unless you give some more examples to show the variation in names.

Answer (score 0):

If You want a one line command, its better to use `cut` instead.

`ls rmsf_visu_AT1_dry_apo.2rep.step7_1.pdb|cut -c11-26`

If the filename length is variable, then use this:

```
ls rmsf_visu_AT1_dry_apo.2rep.step7_1.pdb|cut -d_ -f3-5|cut -d. -f1-2
```